# How to Implement SAM Broadcaster with Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, plugin-recommendation, radio

I want to implement [SAM Broadcaster software](http://spacial.com/sam-broadcaster) in wordpress. This is radio automation software. my client wants to implement with wordpress because he want to add some articles and videos regularly with this software.

Current Site: [www.radiojazzplus.com](http://www.radiojazzplus.com)

Already some of them Implemented in wordpress and their Link is

1.http://classicalmusicbroadcast.com

2.http://operamusicbroadcast.com.

i can't open both sites due to ip lock for my country (India).I found plugin here [Sam Broadcaster plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sam-broadcaster-wordpress-plugin/) but it's not working fully.

If you had done already like please Help me to figure out this problem. i was digging my head for past 4 days and i want your help friends.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: What exactly is the Q?

Comment: Want to Embed This software in Wordpress. This is the Q @:kaiser

Comment: Then I'd offer either a big bounty as it's a list of tasks and no "some lines of code and go", or search for a professional to hire. I mean, honestly - at least _you_ get paid to do this, right?

Comment: You are Correct @:kaiser ..am not asking like this." please send me the full code without debug".. i just want to know about the implementation steps .of course i can't able to hire a professional because this is very low budget project($100 with theme).please just show the path or tips. this is i expect. Thanks

Comment: The sites you have given are not really integrating Sam Broadcaster into WordPress. What they are doing is simply using iframes in their pages to load in the HTML generated from a stand alone version of Sam Broadcaster.

Comment: Ok, how about telling me what you've done so far? Could you share of your code or concept and tell what works and what not?

Comment: There's no question here, flagging to close

Comment: I don't see a question here, I see a job that you are passing on from yourself to others. Please elaborate on what have you tried and what exactly you need help with, otherwise this is out of scope and will be closed.

Comment: i had tried with iframe and it's not working.the core files like php editable files are stored in C:programfiles/.... like that. so am confused with this.. i don't know how to start and where to start? please friends, am not passing any job here, actually i don't know and want to work myself.am just asking "How to Start?"details to experts. That's It. Am newbie to this software...

Comment: If your client purchased a license of SAM Broadcaster, then you should have access to their Support Forum/Help Center/etc. So far it's no WP Question.

Comment: I am sorry but no matter what your intentions are, it doesn't change the fact that what you are doing **is** passing a job. Please seek support from software's developers first (as suggested above) and then you might have more specific and actionable questions about details of making it work with WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and only thing I can add to this Q is: Avoid this plugin. At least the free version (don't know how the paid version bahaves).

I got dozens of errors and notices with `WP_DEBUG` set to `TRUE`.

- wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks.
- has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead.
- Undefined index: sradiobfm_hidden in (...)\plugins\sam-broadcaster-wordpress-plugin\sradiobfm_admin_settings.php on line 5

It messes up all the admin menu, crashes the complete styles, etc. I'd say: Just tell your client to leave this plugin as it won't be a good choice (not reliable).

Comment: Thanks for your Great answer with Explanation.Can you tell "What is the Way to Implement this Sam Broadcaster with wordpress?" . can we do by inserting iframe like current site? can you help me ?